# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebugAndroidTest'

Tags: android, instrumentation

When I run InstrumentationTest,It's build failed.The error message:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebugAndroidTest'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/test/InstrumentationRegistry.class
>   Somebody tell me why?thank you for you notice

Comment: check which library or jar make it duplicate and add your build.gradle

Comment: There is no duplication of files,Just miss words in my build.gradle: packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

Comment: Any updates here? I have same issue, already tried different options to exclude AndroidTestCompile packages, but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's just miss words in build.gradle :

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
}
```

But when I add those words,build failed too，and report other error message :

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define         Landroid/support/test/BuildConfig;
Error:Execution failed for task   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:    org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program    Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```